# Remove rails presenter object assignment from view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, decorator, presenter

I am using a namespaced Presenter object to help refactor some view presentation logic for my model attributes.

For one object being sent from the controller I would do

```
@user = Users::UserPresenter.new(@user)
```

and that works fine.  For a query of users, I created a .present() method that maps and applies the UserPresenter.new to each user, so I do

```
@users = Users::UserPresenter.present(users)
```

and that works fine.  But what about when I am passing an object that then iterates through a relationship in the view.  A simple example would be

```
  <% appointment.users.each do |user| %>
    <% user = Users::UserPresenter.new(user) %>
    <li> <%= user.age%></li>
  <% end %>
```

A more complex example would be

```
  <% appointment.appointment_host.family.users.each do |user| %>
    <% user = Users::UserPresenter.new(user) %>
    <li> <%= user.age%></li>
  <% end %>
```

user_presenter.rb

```
module Users
  class UserPresenter < SimpleDelegator 
     # methods
  end
end
```

I don't like having to set the Presenter object in the view.  What is a better way to handle this?  Ideally using similar patterns as I have so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could create a hierarchy of presenters similar to model associations, and then pass only the root presenters to the view. Something like this:

```
class AppointmentPresenter
  def initialize(appointment)
    @appointment = appointment
  end

  def users
    Users::UserPresenter.present(@appointment.users)
  end

  def host_family_users
    Users::UserPresenter.present(@appointment.appointment_host.family.users)
  end

  # or perhaps even indeed create a presenter for each collection:
  def appointment_host
    AppointmentHostPresenter.new(@appointment.appointment_host)
    # this presenter would have the `family` method returning a FamilyPresenter, etc.
  end
end
```

I.e. some kind of "decorators" for the model associations, returning presenters instead of model objects.

Comment: i updated my question with my presenter class.  Is it preferable to do an initialize method versus using inherit SimpleDelegator?